# Dialog form in wpf change content

Tags: wpf, dialog

I want to display a dialog form for new and edit actions... However title, buttons , and few other things should change.
I am wondering how i could implement this. Provide an enum value at constructor ? Like   Mode.New or Mode.Edit ? Is there a way to avoid writing code like spNewButtons.Visibillity=Collapsed   .. etc , and put it inside wpf ?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind visibility with your `mode` property, and create a specific [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) to convert the mode to a proper Visibility value. ie:

```
<StakPanel Visibility={Binding Mode,Converter={StaticResource myProperConverter}}></StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually my WPF dialogs are all ContentControls that get displayed in a Popup.

My code usually looks like this:

```
<Grid Name="RootPanel">

    <!-- Other Content -->

    <!-- Popup is always last so it gets displayed on top of other contnet -->
    <local:PopupPanel
        local:PopupPanel.PopupParent="{Binding ElementName=RootPanel}"
        local:PopupPanel.IsPopupVisible="{Binding IsPopupVisible}"

        local:PopupPanel.PopupEnterKeyCommand="{Binding SaveCommand}"
        local:PopupPanel.PopupEscapeKeyCommand="{Binding CancelCommand}">

        <DockPanel>
            <!-- Header -->
            <Label DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="{Binding PopupHeader}" />

            <!-- Buttons -->
            <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding PopupSaveCommand}" />
                <Button Content="Cancel" Command="{Binding PopupCancelCommand}" />
            </StackPanel>

            <!-- Actual content displayed is determined by DataTemplates -->
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding PopupContent}" />
        </DockPanel>
    </local:PopupPanel>

</Grid>
```

I removed a lot of the styles to make this easier to read, but you can see the general idea of how it's put together. My ViewModel usually contains properties for `IsPopupVisible`, `PopupContent`, and `PopupHeader`, and commands for `PopupSaveCommand` and `PopupCancelCommand`

I use [my own custom popup](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/popup-panel-for-wpf/) in most cases, although the same thing could be done with a WPF popup.